# Highcharts - prevent large marker from overflowing axes - my bubbles are escaping =(

Tags: highcharts

This picture should say it all.  I'm trying to implement a bubble chart with HighCharts (basically a scatter plot with marker size changing based on some metric).  Sadly, some of my bubbles are trying to escape the chart, overflowing the axis and making things look messy and hard-to-read.  Any way to prevent this?  Obviously I could manipulate the range of the axes, but I'd rather just hide the overflowing part of the bubble.  Besides, this is not an option if the x-axis is required to start at 0 (for example).  Pics:

Overflow (Highcharts):

[image: Overflowing bubble]

No Overflow (Chart director).  This is what I want:

[image: Bubble cut off nicely]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice to try to use v3.0 beta release which should solve your problem. Please take look at example:

http://jsfiddle.net/g8JcL/68/

```
 $('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts bubbles with radial gradient fill'
    },

    xAxis: {
        minPadding:0,
        gridLineWidth: 1
    },

    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false
    },

    series: [ {
        data: [
            [42, 38, 500],
            [6, 18, 1],
            [0, 93, 505],
            [57, 2, 90],
            [80, 76, 22],
            [11, 74, 96],
            [88, 56, 10],
            [30, 47, 49],
            [57, 62, 98],
            [4, 16, 16],
            [46, 10, 11],
            [22, 87, 89],
            [57, 91, 82],
            [45, 15, 98]
        ]
    }]

});
```

Comment: This would seem to be the way to go.  Thanks :)