# Highcharts - Bubble chart - Proportional bubbles

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization, bubble-chart

I'm producing Highcharts bubble charts based on user selected data.

I'd have expected the bubbles on the charts to be proportionally sized to each other (i.e. the bubble for a '2' is consistent through multilpe charts) however, it seems to be based on the range of points on the chart.

This is highlighted in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moonspace/svcuLgso/)

As you can see, the '2's in chart #2 are the same size as the '6' in chart #1.
I'd like the '2' in chart #2 to match the size of the '2' in chart #1.

Is there any way of achieving this ?

Here's the code:

```
jQuery(function () {

var data1 = [{ x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, label: 'data #1' },
            { x: 1, y: 1, z: 1, label: 'data #2' },
            { x: 2, y: 2, z: 2, label: 'data #3' },
            { x: 3, y: 3, z: 3, label: 'data #4' },
            { x: 4, y: 4, z: 4, label: 'data #5' },
            { x: 5, y: 5, z: 5, label: 'data #6' },
            { x: 6, y: 6, z: 6, label: 'data #7' }]; 

var data2 = [{ x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, label: 'data #1' },
            { x: 1, y: 1, z: 1, label: 'data #2' },
            { x: 2, y: 1, z: 1, label: 'data #3' },
            { x: 3, y: 2, z: 2, label: 'data #4' },
            { x: 4, y: 2, z: 2, label: 'data #5' },
            { x: 5, y: 1, z: 1, label: 'data #6' },
            { x: 6, y: 0, z: 0, label: 'data #7' }]; 

jQuery('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
        credits: false,

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    title: {
        text: ''
    },

    xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
       categories: ['data #1', 'data #2', 'data #3', 'data #4', 'data #5', 'data #6', 'data#7']
    },

    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: true,
        min: -1,
        max: 7,
        showFirstLabel: false,
        showLastLabel: false,
        tickInterval: 1,
        title: {
            text: 'Score'
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}'
        },
        maxPadding: 0.2
    },

    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        headerFormat: '<table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3>{point.label}</h3></th></tr>' +
            '<tr><th>Score:</th><td>{point.y}</td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        followPointer: true
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{ data: data1 }]
});


jQuery('#container2').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
        credits: false,

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    title: {
        text: ''
    },

    xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
       categories: ['data #1', 'data #2', 'data #3', 'data #4', 'data #5', 'data #6', 'data#7']
    },

    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: true,
        min: -1,
        max: 7,
        showFirstLabel: false,
        showLastLabel: false,
        tickInterval: 1,
        title: {
            text: 'Score'
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}'
        },
        maxPadding: 0.2
    },

    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        headerFormat: '<table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3>{point.label}</h3></th></tr>' +
            '<tr><th>Score:</th><td>{point.y}</td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        followPointer: true
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{ data: data2 }]
});


});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is similar to what I had proposed as an answer to another bubble chart question elsewhere on Stack Overflow:

[Highcharts 3.0 Bubble Chart -- Controlling bubble sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706060/highcharts-3-0-bubble-chart-controlling-bubble-sizes/17727011#17727011)

For your situation, it seems adding a transparent, non-interactive "dummy" bubble with the largest possible dimensions in your chart will keep each of the other bubbles in the proper proportions to one another:

```
series: [{ data: data2 }, 
    // dummy series to keep all the bubbles in proportion
    {name: 'dummy series',
    data: [{x:6,y:6,z:6}], 
    showInLegend: false, 
    color: 'transparent', 
    enableMouseTracking: false}
]
```

Here's an updated version of your fiddle with this fix: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/svcuLgso/13/

Please let me know if this solves your issue!

Comment: You're so welcome! I came across that solution quite by accident one day, so I'm happy that it worked out for you. Please let me know if I can be of further assistance.